# cut() function appears to group observations incorrectly

Tags: r

Here's an example of how the group label from `cut()` doesn't seem accurate. The observation with x1=200 is classified in the [0,200) group of x2, which is wrong. The label can be fixed by increasing `dig.lab`, but I still think the default rounding should give a result for x2 with face validity. Is this a bug?

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(100, 100.5, 200, 200.5))
df$x2 <- cut(df$x1, breaks = c(0,200.1,999), right = FALSE)
df$x3 <- cut(df$x1, breaks = c(0,200.1,999), right = FALSE, dig.lab = 4)
df
#      x1        x2          x3
# 1 100.0   [0,200)   [0,200.1)
# 2 100.5   [0,200)   [0,200.1)
# 3 200.0   [0,200)   [0,200.1)
# 4 200.5 [200,999) [200.1,999)
```

Comment: *"200 is classified in the `[0,200)` group"*: why are you surprised that 200 is binned between 0 and 200.1? As you say, it's a label thing, so ... what exactly is your issue here?

Comment: My concern is with face validity of the label. For example, I sent a dataset to a collaborator today, and he might look at this and think something is wrong

Comment: I understand your point (and don't disagree that the label is misleading). But sometimes automated beautification is wrong ... this is one example where you need to override the automation.

Comment: For this simple example, I agree I should just override the automation. But in a real analysis, I have two concerns about having this as the default behavior... 1) beautification is nice, but should we really make it the default if it makes the label misleading? and 2) it can be very difficult to catch cases when this might be an issue (i.e. when I should override) and it could lead to misunderstandings down the analytic pipeline

Comment: I understand. (1) I almost always use `cut(..., labels=FALSE)`. I often find default behavior in some R functions to be a little perplexing, but many of these defaults have been in place for so long that changing them would have significant side-effects. (2) This mis-behavior appears to be problematic in your case, but it is almost certainly contextual: this issue does not come up often, suggesting that most users either don't use it or are comfortable with the defaults. (Or don't notice the errors.) Catching and fixing these errors is contextual, so they should be up to the user/programmer.

Comment: Changing the default to `cut(..., labels=FALSE)` would take care of my issue. Users would need to opt into the nicer-but-potentially-incorrect labels. But I also understand that there's a tradeoff with the inconvenience of making a change. It's worth it in my opinion, but I guess the decision is up to the people who maintain base R. Is there a way to report it to them?

Comment: You can always start with a bug report. Conveniently, there's a function for that: [`?bug.report`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/bug.report.html).

Comment: You can "report" concerns about R not behaving in the manner described in documentation or help pages, but you are expressing concern over what you consider an infelicity. It's unlikely the R Core would consider this an issue for further effort. There's already  the 'dig.lab' parameter.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll submit a bug report because the label could automatically include the number of significant digits necessary to make the label accurate

Comment: How many digits is that?  200.1 isn't the exact value that's stored (since that value can't be stored).  The exact value is something like 200.09999999999999432.

Comment: I'm thinking it would incrementally increase the significant digits until there's not an inconsistency. In this case it would round 200.0999999999999432 (or whatever) to 200.1. It could either make all cut points 4 significant digits, or maybe it would change 200 to 200.1 while leaving the others unaffected. Both approaches would work

Comment: Some developers define a different function that behaves as they desire. Harrell's Hmisc has a `cut2` with different arrangement of the open and closed ends of intervals as well as a `g` parameter. That's what I prefer, so I just use his defaults. My advice is to not waste your time or the R-Core members' time on a suggestion that will almost assuredly not be accepted. I don't think that the bug tracking pages are open to the "general public". You needed to be given some sort subscriber access which will usually only be done if you first submit diff on the R source to the R-devel mailing list.

Comment: To add to @42-'s comment, there have been many frustrations with base functions over the years, which is what has led people like Hadley Wickham to create a revised set of functions in his packages, such as `dplyr::if_else()` over `ifelse()`, `readr::read_csv()` over `read.csv()`, or `stringr::str_replace()` over `gsub()`. Given that the R-Core team has no interest in implementing his variations of base functions, I also doubt that they'll have an interest in changing `cut()`'s behaviour. Instead, I'd advise to create a new function for yourself or `Hmisc::cut2()`, and use it going forward.

Comment: Fair points @42- @Phil, albeit disappointing. For comparison, `pandas.cut([100, 100.5, 200, 200.5], bins = [0, 200.1, 999], right = False)` works as expected in Python: `[[0.0, 200.1), [0.0, 200.1), [0.0, 200.1), [200.1, 999.0)]` :/